# How to get gRPC status from grpc::CompletionQueue Usage

Tags: c++, grpc, grpc-c++

Say you use grpc::CompletionQueue::AsyncNext or Next and get ok=false. How does one go about figuring out what the specific status code (https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/md_doc_statuscodes.html) related to the failure? In a normal stream, this would result in the status code through an exception or some other way, but I can't tell how to get it from CompletionQueue.

Additional context, I want to either retry or exit completely based on the particular status code of the failure.

GRPC CompletionQueue API doesn't seem to show any direct connection between the two. I've tried ClientAsyncReader->Finish after the initial CompletionQueue ok=false, but that returns a success status.

Comment: ok is for the async operation, status is for the call, and a call may consist of many operations. Some async operations (e.g. alarm) may not be associated with any call. When you submit an operation to the completion queue, you give a tag, the tag is how you figure out what operation the completion is for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait when your `ClientAsyncReader->Finish` will be processed.
On the next `grpc::CompletionQueue::AsyncNext` your relevant gRPC context from Completion Queue (same tag as in Finish call) will be updated with new gRPC status.